# Should I put the login view as part of my application?

Tags: marionette

I'm studying @marionettejs It's a fantastic library. 
Almost all examples start with the whole application, ie, with all regions, like navbar, content, menu, footer, etc. 
In  my application, I have the initial screen that show the login form where the user need fill to access the application.
My question is: Should I put this login form view as part of app?
Do you have some example, if applicable?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you want to do. The reason most examples you see have the full application, is because it is "behind" the log in screen. In other words, the workflow is like this:

1. User logs in
2. User is redirected to page containing the Marionette app
3. The app is started

You can of course manage the login process with Backbone/Marionette as well, but it tends to be more work.