# Having the landing/auth apart from the Marionette app

Tags: javascript, ajax, backbone.js, marionette

Both [Derick Bailey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18151759/marionette-js-with-rails-devise-authentication) and [David Sulc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17394094/should-i-put-the-login-view-as-part-of-my-application) are very conclusive at the time to have the Landing page and auth logic (+ login/signup forms) separed from the actual Marionette app. However, I haven't been able to find any example nor explanation of how should this be handled and thus, I have few doubts:

CHANGING THE INDEX.HTML

1. The index.html won't be loading the Marionette app anymore. This means that when loading example.com we will end up in a simple landing page even if the user is authenticated (localStorage has his token credentials stored). I understand that this simple landing should somehow handle that if the user has stored credentials, the user should be immediately redirected to a app.html that will actually load the Marionette app, with the users account and the initially accessed route. In other words:

   - 1. The url fragment is stored.
   - 2. Check if user is logged in
   - 3. If the user is logged in, then load app.html which will load the app (how to load the app for a certain route?)
   - 4. If the user is not logged in, then do nothing

LOGGING IN

2. In the case the user is not logged in and logs in. Independently of if index.html has the login form or we have redirected the user to login.html, our auth logic has to be independant of the app. This means login.html has to include a .js that will make an ajax call against out API.

   - 1. User enters credentials
   - 2. AJAX call to check credentials
   - 3. If API returns token, then store credentials in localStorage and load app.html (which will load the marionette app)

SIGNING UP

3. The user signs up at /signup signup.html or index.html if this includes a sign up form. Whichever HTML is loaded, it must include the necessary js logic to make an ajax call to the API for a new user.

   - 1. User enters new account data
   - 2. Our independant js makes an ajax call to the API
   - 3. If creation successful we store the data to localStorage and load app.html (which loads the app)
   - 4. If not, we show errors

---

And you'll say I'm missing the question. My question is, are these workflows correct?

1. Which workflow do you normally use?
2. How do you structure this code inside the marionette app project folder?
3. If you know of any simple examples on github on how to approach this I'd be very happy to learn about them!

Answer (score 1):

Well, in case someone stumbles upon this question, I finally decided to have the landing/auth logic inside the Marionette app. This way I keep my backend to be only an API REST, and I don't need of any further backend to serve me more pages.